# get files from a directory with a specific length and starting with specific character

Tags: python

I was wondering if I could search combining both, search for a specific length while starting with a specific character like "s".
I would use for searching the character:

```
ls -d /etc/[s]*
```

and for searching the length:

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep  -regex '.*/.{6}$'
```

Is it possible to combine both? Thank you guys

Comment: Your question is tagged python, why are you using shell commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `s?????` will match filenames with 6 characters starting with `s`. In filename wildcards, `?` matches any character.

You can use `glob.glob()` to search for them.

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('/etc/s?????')
```

If you're looking for a shell solution, you can use the same wildcards:

```
ls -d /etc/s?????
```

or

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -name 's?????'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a python solution, the easiest way would be to filter out files that are 6 characters long and start with `s`:

```
from os import listdir

files = [f for f in listdir("/etc") if len(f) == 6 and f.startswith("s")]

print(files)
# ['shadow', 'shells', 'subgid', 'subuid']
```

If you really need regex then you could try something like this:

```
from os import listdir
from re import match

files = [f for f in listdir("/etc") if match("^s.{5}$", f)]

print(files)
# ['shadow', 'shells', 'subgid', 'subuid']
```